# New Twilio alarm generated with every call - no errors or warnings in the logs

Tags: twilio, alarm

I've turned on one of the new Beta Alarms for all warnings and errors.  The alarm is triggered every time there's an incoming call (I usually get 2 when the call initiates and two more when the call completes), however there are no errors or warnings shown in the error logs.  Is this expected behavior?  On one hand it's been handy because we've had one caller who doesn't respond to the prompts and just hangs on, chewing up minutes.  On the other hand, it's annoying to get these when calls are being processed normally.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug, I suggest opening a ticket with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) to investigate. If the Alarm event says, `Any Warning or Error` but the webhook generated says, Log   info, something seems off.